# Laravel compact is not working

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm trying to make a posting system, with a resource routing combination on the posts. When I try to run the app to view the posts, it returns an error stating that the posts could not be found within the view. I have the controller code for the index and the show functions:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::latest()->get();

    return view('view', compact('posts'));
}

public function show(Post $post)
{
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

The view that I have for the app uses the post variable to display the posts:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <!-- Posts will be displayed on the same panel -->
                    <div class="panel-body" id="view">
                        @foreach($posts as $post)
                            <article id="post">
                                <a href="/view/posts{{ $post->id }}">
                                    {{ $post->title }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="body">
                                    {{ $post->body }}
                                </div>

                                <!-- Footer for posts will include interaction features -->
                            </article>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there something that the laravel installation isn't doing correctly? Is the compact function set up correctly?

Comment: Try to `return $posts;` to seeit actually returns any value, if it doesn't  please share the `latest()` method, your error might be from that since your code is correct

Comment: Your question is confusing, you have 2 return views but showing only 1 page. Also as @hazelcodes, make sure you got results. `dd($posts)`

Answer (score 0):

The return of the index action is wrong

```
return view('view', compact('posts'));
```

Change **'view'** with **'posts'**

Comment: What do you mean by change view with posts?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller index function should be something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::get();
    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: 'view' is a view blade that I want to send the posts to, in the order of earliest to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Use compact('posts')

If you're a beginner checkout the laracasts video series to get a good understanding of the Laravel framework.